# On Parse.com, one big upload/download or many small. Which is better?

Tags: ios, download, upload, parse-platform

Here is a question related to the best way to use Parse.com, when uploading and downloading data to the cloud.
Eventhough the question is simple I didn’t find any clear answer with a quick internet search.
The case is an iOS app from which users, can upload and more often download data, to and from Parse.com.
Each time an upload happens, the data shows up naturally into chunks.

Is is better to upload the chunks one after the other as they come?

(Using a `[pFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:…]` statement for each chunk)

Or is it better to group the chunks together into one block, and only after, upload this block in one time?

Comment: When you say "Data" here, do you mean big chunks of binary data (i.e. images), or small objects (i.e. records). I assume from your code snippet where you refer to a PFObject, that you are talking about creating/updating records?

Comment: This is close-vote bait for being opinion based.  Consider editing into a much more specific question that includes the type and size of big vs. small data, the pace of arrival, how timely must the data be on the server, etc.

Comment: When I say “data” here I mean: text and sound.
About 30% of the chunks I am talking about are around 10 seconds sound files;
about 70% are around 200 characters text.
An average user would normally make no more than one download a day. Only some of the users (less than 5%) will be concerned by uploading data.